# SQL Query with multiple conditions on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to write a query with condition on dates for below table and sometimes it requires great thinking.

```
StartDtm                             StopDtm
2013-11-03 00:00:00.000               NULL
2013-11-05 08:00:00.000               NULL
2013-11-18 09:00:00.000               NULL
2013-11-18 08:00:00.000               NULL
2013-11-19 08:00:00.000              2013-11-26 07:59:00.000
2013-11-20 08:00:00.000              2013-11-27 07:59:00.000
2013-11-19 08:00:00.000              2013-12-19 07:59:00.000
```

The table shows the task start date and task end date. Start date can never be null.
Last record shows that the task starts at 19th Nov. and will end at 19th Dec. So if I pass any dates, it should show all the tasks which need to be performed on any date between passed date range.

Conditions are as below:

1.Any date or both date parameters may be null. If so all data should come.

2.If @StartDtm is null and @StopDtm is passed, then it should bring all data based on StopDtm field only but it should not bring those data whose StartDtm is greater than @StopDtm. Same for @StopDtm parameter

3.If StopDtm field is null, It should bring all data based on StartDtm field only

I tried few ways but not succeeded. I to keep condition as short as possible. If possible, then please provide multiple queries with little explanation.

My query is as below:

```
DECLARE @StartDtm datetime='2013-11-15'
DECLARE @StopDtm datetime='2013-11-21'

select * from #TempTbl
where  ((StartDtm<=@StartDtm OR @StartDtm IS NULL)  AND (StopDtm>=@StopDtm OR StopDtm IS NULL))
    OR((StartDtm>=@StartDtm OR @StartDtm IS NULL) AND (StopDtm>=@StopDtm AND StartDtm<= @StopDtm OR StopDtm IS NULL OR @StopDtm IS NULL))
    OR((StartDtm>=@StartDtm OR @StartDtm IS NULL) AND (StopDtm<=@StopDtm OR StopDtm IS NULL OR @StopDtm IS NULL))
```

Thanks in advance..
The question is already asked in StackOverflow but I cannot find how to migrate it here. So asked here again.

**Created another query which seems working fine:**

```
DECLARE @StartDtm datetime='2013-11-20'
DECLARE @StopDtm datetime='2013-11-30'

IF(@StartDtm is null)
begin
    SET @StartDtm='1900-01-01'
end
IF(@StopDtm IS NULL)
begin
    SET @StopDtm='9999-12-31'
end

select * from #TempTbl
where (startDtm<= @StartDtm and ISNULL(StopDtm,@StopDtm)>=@StopDtm )
  OR(StartDtm>=@StartDtm and ISNULL(StopDtm,@StopDtm)<=@StopDtm )
  OR(StartDtm between @StartDtm AND @StopDtm and ISNULL(StopDtm,@StopDtm)>=@StopDtm  )
  OR(StartDtm<=@StartDtm AND ISNULL(StopDtm,@StopDtm) between @StartDtm AND  @StopDtm)
```

Suggest if any logical error/change/improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
WHERE (StartDtm <= @StopDtm AND @StopDtm >= @StartDtm) OR (StartDtm >= @StartDtm AND StopDtm IS NULL)
```

work for you?

Comment: Yes. It should work. The purpose is to get the task list. if give date range falls in between StartDtm and StopDtm then the condition before OR will work but if the StopDtm is null in table, in that case it need to operate on StartDtm only and StopDtm condition check should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WHERE (@StartDtm IS NULL OR StartDtm = @StartDtm)
  AND (@StopDtm IS NULL OR StopDtm = @StopDtm)
  OR ( ISNULL(@StartDtm,@StopDtm) = NULL OR (StartDtm> @StartDtm AND StopDtm < @StopDtm ) )
```

Comment: Its not working. Check it for give date range in question. For that, it should give all records but your condition does not give any record.

Comment: @ChiragFanse I couldn't understand why for given parameter range ('2013-11-15',2013-11-21'), the query should give all records.
maybe it is good to describe your business domain instead your database enviroment

Comment: First four records dont have StopDtm & hence are considered to end on infinite date.So even if few of them have StartDtm<'2013-11-15', it will come in a result as StopDtm(Which is infinite) will always be <'2013-11-21' meaning that the occurrence of these tasks will fall in given range. For remaining 3 records, tasks are starting after 15th but will end after 21. So on a calender of 2013-11-15 to 2013-11-21, there are occurrence of these tasks. The dates columns shows that tasks starts at date X and will continue to occur till date y.If any occurrence come in a range, it should result in o/p